# CakePHP how to share session with Vbulletin

Tags: cakephp, vbulletin

how to put folder of vbulletin and modify .htaccess file in cake PHP in purpose use them in same session ? if it possible, plz help me by post the way to put the folder vbulletin in order  request access from localhost/forum or localhost/app_name/forum?

I am tried to install vbullentin in webroot and modify .htaccess. It can access from localhost/forum ( app cake can access from http://localhost ) but both couldnt share session .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for: 
https://github.com/ceeram/static_bakery/blob/master/src/articles/2010/01/Vbulletin-Bridge-For-CakePHP.rst

A full example of this here: https://github.com/enangyusup/vbulletin-cakephp

There doesn't seem to be any proper documentation, so you'll need to snoop around the code a bit. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, both links are now dead (404).